# Cassandra AssertionError: length is not > 0

Tags: cassandra

Running into the following exception trying to start my 3.0.5 cassandra cluster.  Not sure what this means or how to proceed.

```
INFO  14:14:05 Initializing keyspace.table
Exception (java.lang.AssertionError) encountered during startup: length is not > 0: 0
java.lang.AssertionError: length is not > 0: 0
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.ByteBufferUtil.readBytes(ByteBufferUtil.java:408)
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.metadata.CompactionMetadata$CompactionMetadataSerializer.deserialize(CompactionMetadata.java:93)
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.metadata.CompactionMetadata$CompactionMetadataSerializer.deserialize(CompactionMetadata.java:73)
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.metadata.MetadataSerializer.deserialize(MetadataSerializer.java:123)
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.metadata.MetadataSerializer.deserialize(MetadataSerializer.java:94)
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.metadata.MetadataSerializer.mutateLevel(MetadataSerializer.java:133)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.LeveledManifest.add(LeveledManifest.java:132)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.LeveledCompactionStrategy.addSSTable(LeveledCompactionStrategy.java:278)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.CompactionStrategyManager.startup(CompactionStrategyManager.java:135)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.CompactionStrategyManager.reload(CompactionStrategyManager.java:187)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.CompactionStrategyManager.<init>(CompactionStrategyManager.java:75)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.<init>(ColumnFamilyStore.java:394)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.<init>(ColumnFamilyStore.java:353)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.createColumnFamilyStore(ColumnFamilyStore.java:560)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.createColumnFamilyStore(ColumnFamilyStore.java:537)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.Keyspace.initCf(Keyspace.java:368)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.Keyspace.<init>(Keyspace.java:305)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.Keyspace.open(Keyspace.java:129)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.Keyspace.open(Keyspace.java:106)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:250)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:551)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:679)
ERROR 10:37:43 Exception encountered during startup
```

Comment: there any context right before that in log at least which table it is?

Comment: Yes, it does describe the table  as such INFO  14:14:05 Initializing keyspace.table.  I updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your one table looks to have a corrupted metadata component. Try running `sstablescrub` (https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.2/cassandra/tools/toolsSSTableScrub.html) on the sstables in the affected table and remove the offending one. You should only need to run the manifest check (`--manifest-check` option) since thats whats actually failing in your stacktrace. Once node starts up again be sure to run a repair on it to restore any lost data.